# How can I find a Uniform Resource Identifier?

Tags: html, .net, http, bots

I understand that a URI is the combination of a URL and URN. The URL is the easy part, but I do not know where to look for the URN. Can this be found in the html of a specific page? How then is the proper way to concatenate the two (URL and URN)? I am attempting to use .net's httpclient.UploadValues() and need a URI.

EDIT: As stated below URIs are not combinations of URLs and URNs

Comment: Why did you down vote me? I have tried searching for an answer for this and have been unsuccessful. I am new to HTML and HTTP and understand this question may be poorly worded. Please provide an explanation as to why you down voted me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking pretty loosely, it's not a combination of a URL and a URN (Universal Resource Name). It's either a URL or a URN. In fact a URL is one type of URN.

So your URI is just your URL for HTTP.

Comment: TY for clarification. I would like to login to https://shipcsx.com/pub_sx_mainpagepublic_jct/sx.shipcsxpublic/Main and am using: client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", myCollection); myCollection contains username password pairs. How can I tell if my login was successful?

Comment: Actually, both URLs and URNs are URIs.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are URIs, and so are URNs. So your question doesn't make sense. See RFC 3986.